# JSF2.0 - Facelets URL Masking

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I want to mask my JSF2.0 Facelets URLS. Is there any solution available to meet my need? We don’t want to go for any third party apis. I am fine with customising my ViewHandler class. Please help.

Thanks,
Nanjundan Chinnasamy

Comment: What do you mean by "masking"?

Comment: Yes, i meant "URL masking" Kolossues.

Comment: You're looking to write your own [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)? Too messy